# Ruby error while migrating database and seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

http://pastebin.com/a8fVSCcA
I am trying to implement a Questions and answers model, I've added a has_many and a belongs_to but they seem to be causing errors.

```
reconcubed@blccit:~/workspace (master) $ rake db:migrate
== 20150509125146 CreateQuestions: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:questions)
-- has_many(:answers)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `has_many' for #<CreateQuestions:0x00000006b93010>/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:648:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20150509125146_create_questions.rb:7:in `block in change'
```

Problematic code:

```
#Questions Model
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :questions do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.text :body
     t.boolean :resolved
     has_many :answers
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end


#Answers
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :answers do |t|
     t.text :body
     t.references :question, index: true
     belongs_to :question
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: I pulled the relevant code from pastebin to here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `has_many` or `belongs_to`in a migration.

Remove the `has_many` from questions migration, and remove the `belongs_to` from the answers migration.  And you should be fine..  These methods need to be added to your models, not your migrations..

Comment: Thank you and I will from here on in :) Thanks!